# Magento 2 origData null in customer_save_before

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3, customer-data

I have created an observer on the `customer_save_before` event. Surprisingly 
`$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getOrigData()` is null. Is my expectation wrong?

This is also happening for `customer_save_commit_after`.

I am looking for an event for which the customer data (new and original) is available, that ideally takes place after the new data was persisted in the db, independent of the area from which it is called frontend or adminhtml.

I have logged all the events that are being dispatched throughout my save customer process and the two events mentioned above made the most sense.

Is there such an event?

Thanks!

Comment: Radu, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer->getOrigData()
```

return null because it never loaded.

[Reference Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4662)

Comment: 3 year old bug. They closed it too. Wow.

Comment: so what is the workaround in the case? explicitly call ```$customer->load``` ?

Comment: $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getData();

Comment: this is not changing anything. I was asking if the workaround for getting the origData is to explicitly call $customer->load

Answer (score 0):

Did you try one of the suggestions in the magento git issue report? Only reason I ask is because he seems so certain. I'm away from computer at the moment so can't test.

```php
$customerData = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');
$newData = $customerData->getData('attriubute_code');
$previousData = $customerData->getOrigData('attribute_code')
```

Comment: not working. $previousData is null