# Magento 2 get customer old and new data on model_save_before and model_save_after event in admin backend

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, backend

I am working on **Admin Actions Log Extension.** For the reference i am using the link below

**https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log-for-magento-2.html**

I want to get **old and new data** of customers when we save the customer.

### EDIT:-

> I'm using these events `model_save_before` and `model_save_after` for
> saving old data to the registry and retrieve it to the save after
> event, but I'm getting old data as null from the registry.

> **SaveBefore.php**

```
$object = $observer->getObject();
$customer = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Backend\Customer')->load($object->getId());
$customerData = $customer->getData();
$this->registryManager->register('adminactionslog_savebefore_data', $customerData, true);
```

> **SaveAfter.php**

```
$oldData = $this->registryManager->registry('adminactionslog_savebefore_data');
// var_dump($oldData); I'm getting this value as null
```

**if anyone has a solution please let me know.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with this particular event

[Magento 2 origData null in customer_save_before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275711/magento-2-origdata-null-in-customer-save-before)

You are going to have to use a different event or code a workaround.

Comment: do you have any suggestions?